xpath wait until page is completely loaded
hi i have  this web page https://www.immobiliare.it/search-list/?idContratto=1&idCategoria=1&criterio=prezzo&ordine=asc&__lang=it&vrt=43.733724%2C10.792973%3B43.723459%2C10.802071%3B43.7267%2C10.809066%3B43.729383%2C10.804582%3B43.732701%2C10.801835%3B43.733554%2C10.800977%3B43.735104%2C10.795913%3B43.733724%2C10.792973&pag=1
i try to take price , description , link , squaremeter, with xpath , but return empty value , i suppose this problemexist because the page is not much fast for load , is possible introduce delay , for wait arrive all data ??
my code :
#!/bin/bash

# Define variables for the URL and browser
sGCitta="?idContratto=1&idCategoria=1&criterio=prezzo&ordine=asc&__lang=it&vrt=43.723444%2C10.802693%3B43.725615%2C10.806384%3B43.735321%2C10.795913%3B43.733709%2C10.791535%3B43.732902%2C10.789347%3B43.725165%2C10.796106%3B43.721583%2C10.799968%3B43.723444%2C10.802693&pag="
sGTypo="search-list"
sGDomain="immobiliare"
iGPagina=1
maxPaginas=1  # Default max pages to 1 initially

# Inizio del ciclo
while [ $iGPagina -le $maxPaginas ]; do

    # Costruzione dell'URL con la variabile iGPagina
    url="https://www.$sGDomain.it/$sGTypo/$sGCitta$iGPagina"
    echo "Fetching URL: $url"
    
    # Ottenimento del contenuto HTML della pagina e salvataggio in dioporco.html
    wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0" --no-check-certificate -q -O dioporco.html "$url"

    # Introdurre un delay di 2 secondi
    sleep 2
    
    # Use xidel to fetch and parse HTML content from the local file
    xidel_output=$(xidel dioporco.html --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0" --xpath '
        array{
            //div[contains(@class,"nd-mediaObject__content in-listingCardPropertyContent")] ! (
                let
                    $price       := .//div[contains(@class, "in-listingCardPrice")]/span/text(),
                    $size        := .//div[contains(@class, "in-listingCardFeatureList__item") and contains(., "m²")]/span/text(),
                    $link        := .//a[contains(@class, "in-listingCardTitle")]/@href,
                    $description := .//a[contains(@class, "in-listingCardTitle")]/@title
                return map{
                    "price"       : $price => replace("^\s+|\s+$", ""),
                    "link"        : $link => replace("^\s+|\s+$", ""),
                    "description" : $description => replace("^\s+|\s+$", ""),
                    "size"        : $size => replace("^\s+|\s+$", ""),
                    "auction"     : contains($description, "asta")
                }
            )
        }
    ')

    echo "$xidel_output" > semi.txt

    # Debug output
    echo "Fetched listings:"
    cat semi.txt

    # Connect to the SQLite database
    db_file="immo.db"

    # Loop through the lines and insert them into the SQLite database
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        # Extract price, size, link, and description values from the lines using jq
        prezzo=$(echo "$line" | jq -r '.price')
        size=$(echo "$line" | jq -r '.size')
        link=$(echo "$line" | jq -r '.link')
        descrizione=$(echo "$line" | jq -r '.description')
        asta=$(echo "$line" | jq -r '.auction')

        # Insert the data into the SQLite database
        sqlite3 "$db_file" "INSERT INTO $sGDomain (prezzo, link, descrizione, metratura, asta) VALUES ('$prezzo', '$link', '$descrizione', '$size', '$asta')"
    done < semi.txt

    # Verifica il numero di pagine solo alla prima iterazione
    if [ $iGPagina -eq 1 ]; then
        # Determine the number of pages using xidel
        maxPaginas=$(xidel demade.html --xpath 'max(//a[contains(@class, "in-pagination__item nd-button nd-button--ghost is-mobileHidden")]/text())')
        echo "MASSIMO PAGINE: $maxPaginas"
        if [ -z "$maxPaginas" ]; then
            maxPaginas=1
        fi
        echo "Max pages to process: $maxPaginas"
    fi

    # Incrementa la variabile iGPagina per la prossima iterazione
    ((iGPagina++))
done

echo "Scraping complete."

i tryed to modify xpath and  also try to download  the  page but not return success

Does this answer your question? How to create a correct XPath for this site?

Once wget finishes all the page content is in the file.

It seems like you didn't check the content of the downloaded page. There's no data in the HTML, you need JavaScript.

yes i saw,  i try to download  with  phantomjs , but also in this mode not  work , i tryed  with perl and  WWW::Mechanize::Chrome;  but when , i try to installs ome depenednces not  go , and now  i try to  create a virtual machine in mint for  test if mechanzie work , if you have some suggest you are welcome , if you have telegram we can chat

You can probably use Python's Scrapy

thanks  but i not want  use python i not know python , i downloaded  a page  with makenzie in perl .....woow finally after  i scrape with bash and xpath ... i hope :D  thanks so much for your support @Fravadona, but you do also a tutorial in youtube ??  for xpath ?

I'm not that comfortable with XPath so no, I didn't make any tutorial.

You should really put more effort in your research and your questioning. Your question should focus on one(!) specific issue you're struggling with, which is really unclear at the moment. There are many things in your Bash script that don't make sense either. Are you struggling with opening the url and html-source? Extracting info? Transforming the info? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254262 and edit your question accordingly! I think your question should be closed as long as you do not.

thanks @Reino  i just resolve in perl with WWW::Mechanize::Chrome , Thank you, I will treasure your suggestion.
